# PowerShell: unable to open image D:\temp\testEnv\1\B\CIMG0727.JPG: Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2584

Tags: powershell, blob

I wrote a powershell script to shrink images (quality and resolution) with imagemagick's convert.exe. Unfortuantely it does not work properly. I'm getting the following error message:

```
PowerShell: unable to open image D:\temp\testEnv\1\B\CIMG0727.JPG: Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2584
```

The complete powershell script: http://pastebin.com/FSxCgeFZ

Can anybody explain me what I am doing wrong? 
I already tried to set the acl to "everybody - full access" - but it still does not work.

Please excuse my bad English. 
Thank you very much in advance for your support!

-patrick

Comment: Where in the script is the error being raised? Also reduce to a minimal recreate and put everything together in this Q.

Comment: Maybe System.Drawing.Image.FromFile() holds r/w lock to the file? Try and dispose the image before calling ImageMagic.

Comment: @anonymous: Thank you very much! After checking the 'if-clause' I made an $image.Dispose() and then I have converted the image - now it works perfectly! Thank you very much!